# Podspec Link Binary Library

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I'm attempting to create a Podspec for: https://github.com/sincerely/shiplib-ios-framework

Pod Lint passes & the files are being added to the project but it does not link the binary "Sincerely" file.  The sample project build fails due to missing files when importing via: `<Sincerely/filename.h>`

```
 Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name  = 'ShipLib'
  s.version = '1.4'
  ...
  s.source = {
    :git => 'https://github.com/sincerely/shiplib-ios-framework.git',
    :tag => 's.version.to_s'
  } 
  s.library = 'Sincerely'
  s.source_files = 'Sincerely.framework','Sincerely.framework/Headers/*.h'
  s.resources = 'Sincerely.framework/Resources/*.{png,nib}'
  s.frameworks = 'AddressBook', 'AddressBookUI', 'SystemConfiguration', 'CoreTelephony'
  s.xcconfig  =   { 'LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS' =>  '$(PODS_ROOT)/ShipLib/' }
end
```

**Edit:**

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name  = 'ShipLib'
  s.version = '1.4'
  s.platform = :ios
  s.summary = 'Allow users to send printed photos from your app.'
  s.author = { 'Sincerely' => 'dev@sincerely.com' }
  s.homepage = 'https://github.com/sincerely/shiplib-ios-framework'
  s.license = { :file => 'LICENSE', :type => 'Commercial' }
  s.source = {
    :git => 'https://github.com/sincerely/shiplib-ios-framework.git',
    :tag => 's.version.to_s'
  }
  s.frameworks = 'AddressBook', 'AddressBookUI', 'SystemConfiguration', 'CoreTelephony'
  s.ios.vendored_frameworks = 'Sincerely.framework'
end
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Headers will not be copied for frameworks, and should not be specified as source files. If all you are looking to do is add the framework as a `vendored_framework`. This is new in [CP 0.23.0](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0230rc1).

From the [Documentation](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0230rc1)

```
  spec.ios.vendored_frameworks = 'Frameworks/MyFramework.framework'
```

**Edit:**
Remove all the stuff about the `.framework` from `s.source_files`. Source files are just that, files, not frameworks.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still failing with "ld: framework not found Sincerely" ... even though I can now see the framework under Pods Project

Comment: Can you post your full, new podfile?

Comment: Added the full Podspec to the question

Comment: Thanks, I cleaned some of that up. The original "Framework not found" problem persists though.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure you're not overriding Framework Search Paths? They should match your Pods.xcconfig

Answer (score 0):

I guess your project maybe lack Sincerely library in Sincerely.framework. And if you are using sourcetree to manage project, it is the sourcetree's bug that cause the problem. Sourcetree does not detect the Sincerely library.