# Cocoapods with custom framework

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods

I want to generate an podspec-file which has an custom framework, one class and a third party framework as dependency.

The single class refers to the custom framework by including one header of that framework. If I run

`pod lib lint`

this error appears :

`- ERROR | [xcodebuild]  /Users/xyz/Documents/iOS/Apps/Sample/Core/Sample.h:10:9: fatal error: 'CustomFramework/Bar.h' file not found`

The related part of my podspec file looks like this:

```
 s.source_files     = 'Core/*' , 'Core/CustomFramework.framework/Headers/*.h'
 s.preserve_paths   = 'Core/CustomFramework.framework/**/*' 
 s.xcconfig         = { 'FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS' => '"${PODS_ROOT}/Headers"' }
 s.frameworks       = 'CustomFramework'
 s.xcconfig         = { 'OTHER_LDFLAGS' => '-ObjC' , 'LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS' =>    '"${PODS_ROOT}/CustomFramework/Headers"'}

 s.dependency 'MapBox', '1.1.0'
```

The single class inherits from class of the MapBox framework.

I feel like I miss something but can not figure out what. Any suggestions or hints?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using `vendored_framework` like explained here: [Podspec Link Binary Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18219286/podspec-link-binary-library)

```
spec.ios.vendored_frameworks = 'Frameworks/MyFramework.framework'
```

Comment: I'm getting headers not found in my example app.